# Display HTML <link> tag as text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, razor

I am trying to display this premade `<link>` tag as plain text:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href= '@(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + item.Path)'>
```

I'd like this to end up looking like:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://example.com/css/a.min' >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it as a string:

```
@("<link rel='stylesheet' href='" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + item.Path + "'>")
```

Comment: Prefect! Thanks!